# Entity Framework - Get count of foreign-key relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dry

I have a simple categories management system.

In my auto-generated EF entities I have two classes of relevance:

```
class Category {
    public EntityCollection<Member> Members { get; }
}
class Member {
    public Category ParentCategory { get; }
}
```

I have a business rule that prevents the deletion of a category if it has any members. I was hoping to accomplish that by doing this:

```
if( category.Members.Count() > 0 ) // then disallow deletion
```

However this call always returns zero.

It appears that I need to actually load the collection first, which incurrs a DB hit:

```
if( !category.Members.IsLoaded ) category.Members.Load();
if( category.Members.Count() > 0 ) // then disallow deletion. This works.
```

I was hoping that the EF would be smart enough to convert the initial `.Count()` call into the SQL `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members WHERE Members.CategoryId = @parentCategoryId` instead of actually loading Members entities and iterating through them in-memory.

Is there a way to do that in EF, or do I need to define a sproc or custom SQL to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ( category.Members.CreateSourceQuery().Count() > 0 )
```